# Angular 8 i18n translate dynamic variable

Tags: angular, angular-i18n

I have in my `app.component.html` an  element that is on every page:

`<h1 i18n="@@titleH1">{{title}}</h1>`

I have a shared service that has a setters and getters:

```
...
title = new BehaviorSubject('Initial Title');

setTitle(title: string) {
this.title.next(title);
}
...
```

**app.component.ts: `ngOnInit`**

```
...
this.sharedService.title.subscribe(updateTitle => this.title = updateTitle);
this.sharedService.setTitle('Dashboard');
...`
```

**product.component.ts: `ngOnInit`**

```
...
this.sharedService.title.subscribe(updateTitle => this.title = updateTitle);
this.sharedService.setTitle('Product');
...
```

When navigate to /dashboard I get Dashboard  in the  when I navigate to /product I get Product in the  which is cool.

How can I translate Dashboard and Product Dinamically as {{title}} will change according to the page.

my `xlf` produced this:

```
     ... 
     <trans-unit id="titleH1" datatype="html">
        <source><x id="INTERPOLATION" equiv-text="{{title}}"/></source>
        <target><x id="INTERPOLATION" equiv-text="{{title}}"/></target>
        <context-group purpose="location">
          <context context-type="sourcefile">src/app/app.component.html</context>
          <context context-type="linenumber">17</context>
        </context-group>
      </trans-unit>
      ...
```

and I added the target tag but not sure how this fit into translation.

Any Ideas. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is Angular 9 with the new $localize which makes it possible to do like so.

**app.component.html:**

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
...
title = $localize`:@@dashboard:Dashboard`;
...
this.sharedService.setTitle(this.title);
```

**product.component.ts:**

```
...
title = $localize`:@@product:Product`;
...
this.sharedService.setTitle(this.title);
```

**messages.xlf:**

```
<trans-unit id="dashboard">
  <source>Dashboard</source>
  <target>Translation here</target>
</trans-unit>
<trans-unit id="product">
  <source>Product</source>
  <target>Translation here</target>
</trans-unit>
```

Nice @Angular team!

Comment: Just a note, as it seems the i18n generator does not catch yet these strings, as this is not officially supported by the Angular team. Maybe we see support on Angular 10?

Comment: Also how to use this with observable typing etc in place? Your title variables are no longer observables...